# SQL Server - JSON type enumeration

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

Given

```
declare @json varchar(max)='{
"name":"John",
"age":30,
"cars": [
    { "make":"Ford", "models":[ "Fiesta", "Focus", "Mustang","Vintage"] ,"price":[1100,200,300,999]},
    { "make":"BMW", "models":[ "320", "X3", "X5" ] },
    { "make":"Fiat", "models":[ "500", "Panda" ] }
] }';
```

The query

```
select * from openjson(@json,'$')
```

returns 3 columns:

```
key value   type
```

I haven't found an enumeration of the *type* column values and their corresponding meaning.

Please point me in the right direction; thanks.

Comment: this will direct you to the right place i guess. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 3):

[From the MSDN page for OPENJSON:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
Value of the Type column    JSON data type
0                           null
1                           string
2                           int
3                           true/false
4                           array
5                           object
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.